# ASP.net static DataView usage accross entire visitors - public static function - is this way thread safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, static, thread-safety

Ok easy question. At the below class do returnAttackDescription function thread safe.

What i mean is assume that 100 different calls is made to that function at the same time with all different parameters (as it takes 3 parameters)

**Would this work thread safe ? if not how can i make it thread safe ? and will this dataview get initialized at the first function call ? or when ?**

thank you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;

public static class Descriptions
{
    private static DataView dvAttacks;

    static Descriptions()
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet dsTempEnemyAttack = DbConnection.db_Select_Query("select AttackType,AttackCategory,BasePower,Accuracy,MoreFacts_tr,MoreFacts_en,Priority from tblAttacks");
            dvAttacks = new DataView(dsTempEnemyAttack.Tables[0]);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    public static string returnAttackDescription(string srAttackName, string srLang, string srCssClassName)
    {
        dvAttacks.RowFilter = "AttackName='" + srAttackName + "'";

        string srReturn = string.Format("<div class=\"{0}\" title=\"" +
                "{0}<hr/>" +
                "Type: {1}<br/>" +
                "Category: {2}<br/>" +
                "Base Power: {3}<br/>" +
                "Accuracy: {4}<br/>" +
                "Priority: {5}<br/>" +
                "Effect: {6}\"></div>", srCssClassName, srAttackName,
                dvAttacks[0]["AttackType"].ToString(),
                dvAttacks[0]["AttackCategory"].ToString(),
                dvAttacks[0]["BasePower"].ToString(),
                dvAttacks[0]["Accuracy"].ToString(),
                dvAttacks[0]["Priority"].ToString(), 
                dvAttacks[0]["MoreFacts_" + srLang].ToString());

        return srReturn;
    }
}
```

**Second possible solution is this thread safe ?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;

public static class Descriptions
{
    private static DataView dvAttacks;

    static Descriptions()
    {
        try
        {
            dsAttacks = DbConnection.db_Select_Query("select AttackName,AttackType,AttackCategory,BasePower,Accuracy,MoreFacts_tr,MoreFacts_en,Priority from tblAttacks");
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    public static string returnAttackDescription2(string srAttackName, string srLang, string srCssClassName)
    {
        var results = (from r in dsAttacks.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                       where r.Field<string>("AttackName") == srAttackName
                       select new
                           {

                               srAttackType = r.Field<string>("AttackType"),
                               srAttackCategory = r.Field<string>("AttackCategory"),
                               irBasePower = r.Field<Int16>("BasePower"),
                               irAccuracy = r.Field<Int16>("Accuracy"),
                               irPriority = r.Field<Int16>("Priority"),
                               srMoreFacts = r.Field<string>("MoreFacts_" + srLang)
                           }
                        ).FirstOrDefault();

        string srReturn = string.Format("<div class=\"{0}\" title=\"" +
        "{0}<hr/>" +
        "Type: {1}<br/>" +
        "Category: {2}<br/>" +
        "Base Power: {3}<br/>" +
        "Accuracy: {4}<br/>" +
        "Priority: {5}<br/>" +
        "Effect: {6}\"></div>", srCssClassName, srAttackName,
        results.srAttackType,
        results.srAttackCategory,
        results.irBasePower,
        results.irAccuracy,
        results.irPriority, results.srMoreFacts);

        return srReturn;
    }
}
```

c# asp.net 4.0

Comment: second possible solution added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions is not actual thread safe, the issue that I see now is that the `dvAttacks.RowFilter` is change the results, so you need to make it thread safe by using a thread lock as:

```
   private static readonly object _lock = new object();

   public static string returnAttackDescription(string srAttackName, string srLang, string srCssClassName)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            dvAttacks.RowFilter = "AttackName='" + srAttackName + "'";

            string srReturn = string.Format("<div class=\"{0}\" title=\"" +
                    "{0}<hr/>" +
                    "Type: {1}<br/>" +
                    "Category: {2}<br/>" +
                    "Base Power: {3}<br/>" +
                    "Accuracy: {4}<br/>" +
                    "Priority: {5}<br/>" +
                    "Effect: {6}\"></div>", srCssClassName, srAttackName,
                    dvAttacks[0]["AttackType"].ToString(),
                    dvAttacks[0]["AttackCategory"].ToString(),
                    dvAttacks[0]["BasePower"].ToString(),
                    dvAttacks[0]["Accuracy"].ToString(),
                    dvAttacks[0]["Priority"].ToString(), 
                    dvAttacks[0]["MoreFacts_" + srLang].ToString());

            return srReturn;
        }
    }
```

The function `Descriptions()` is called when your application starts, make the static data, `DataView dvAttacks` and then this data stay on memory with out change until the application restarts. Each pool of your application have a different set of this data.

On the second solution you only reads them with out affect the `DataView`, so you do not change them to have any conflict. So as it is, work just fine, and all the new memory did not conflict on threads.

This is the parameter that is common `private static DataView dvAttacks;` among threads, and this is only created when your application starts - after that you have only reads... but you must not change it ether inside with out lock.

The different between one and two is that in the first the data changes inside with the filter, on the second you just read them and copy the one you need on new memory, so you only reads them. The second works as it is.

> and will this dataview get initialized at the first function call

Its initialized the moment the application starts and before any page call. You can use the `Debug.Write` to check this out.

Comment: how about second solution ? the data will be always same because it does not change at restart. which one would you prefer ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I do not know what I prefer - maybe place them under timing to see what is faster and select the faster one. I think the first is faster. You can use the `Debug.Write()` to see how the timing work - when for example the `Descriptions()` is called.

Comment: when row filtered the DataView state is changing. That is actually confusing me. Because when many threads make row filter how they get individual results ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I change it, you have right, the DataView must not change with out lock - and you change it with the RowFilter, on second solution you do not change it, you only read it

Comment: well i have to say awesome answer given here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/870b9f88-9800-46d5-b010-d01a8261d23c

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I will read it... well is actually say to you to use `Dictionary<,>` this is something different, yes is better, yes I agree with that. But you get the idea.

Comment: yes i will do that way. ty for your answer too. also how do we use Debug.Write never used it ?